# C++14 on Scientific Linux in Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, redhat, c++14

My operating system is

```
Linux version 2.6.32-220.7.1
(gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
```

And I cannot upgrade it for various reasons which are not up to me, so let's ignore that option.

My version of gcc is

```
Package gcc-c++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

and I have not been able to upgrade it, as can be seen from the message above.

When I use the following flags in eclipse:

```
-c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++1y
```

I get no complaints. However, I cannot do `-std=c++14`, because I get

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++14’
make: *** [2.5/Base.o] Error 1
```

What's really going on here? Am I on C++14 for real? Why can I not upgrade gcc? Why is C++14 flag not Ok, while C++1y is? How can I easily test a C++14 feature to make sure I am really on it?

Thanks

Comment: which redhat linux you are using?

Comment: The linux distro version you have does not update gcc past 4.4.6. because the distro version was frozen and the developers have moved on to provide support for later versions. The expectation is that you upgrade distros or make do with the nice and stable version you have.  You can download updates from other sources if you wish. Incomplete C++14 support starts around gcc 4.9. This link may be of some assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139462/to-use-latest-gcc4-8-1-on-older-linux-svrs-redhat-el-5-7

Comment: I should add that upgrading GCC and the packages needed to support a new GCC may well break some of the other stuff in the linux install. This is why the distro support is frozen. Testing this stuff to ensure an upgrade or fix doesn't break something else can be quite time-consuming, not to mention all the work that goes into massaging the update if it does break something.

Answer (score 1):

GCC 4.4.6 was released in 2012, shortly after the ISO 2011 standard was finalised. C++11 support was still highly experimental and incomplete. For c++14 you need a much more recent compiler.

In Linux, you can install a recent c++ compiler in your user directory. If you then add `$HOME/bin` to `$PATH` and `$HOME/lib` to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you can run a new compiler without root priviledges.

You can just follow the steps in https://gcc.gnu.org/install/, except to use the following command during the 'configuration' step:

```
wget ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/mirror/languages/gcc/releases/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2
tar -jxvf gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2
cd gcc-5.2.0/
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make -j7
make install    # NO root priviledges required!
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
which gcc       # Should say <home dir>/bin/gcc
gcc --version   # Should say 5.2.0
```

I have 8 cores on my laptop, if you have a different number please change the argument in `make -j7` accordingly. It still took a considerable amount of time to build gcc.

Gcc is actually built three times: first an intermediate compiler is made using the available compiler, then the final gcc is built using the intermediate compiler. The intermediate compiler is functionally equivalent to the final compiler, but is less optimized. Finally, gcc is re-compiled using the final compiler, and check if it is exactly the same as the final compiler, thus checking the correctness of the final compiler. And you get a fortan and java compiler as well ;-)

If your `./configure` fails, carefully read the fine print to see which pre-requisites you are missing. I am on Ubuntu, so I can't help you with that...

Comment: Thank you very much, EvertW. Unfortunatelly, though, I cannot open the url you posted. Can you please edit your answer with detailed instructions as to how to install recent C++ compiler?

Then I will go ahead and accept your answer.
Thanks again